# Executing a command on rasbian server from php

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

I have created a web server on my raspberry pi2 device with raspbian.

I have a c++ application(main) that is located on the server in /var/www/cpp.
In my php part im trying to see if the c++ application is running.

```
exec("pidof /var/www/cpp/main 2>&1", $output,$return);

if ($return == 0) {
    $isProcessRunning=true;
} else {
    $isProcessRunning=false;
}
```

This work's very good if i open my page from localhost, but when i open the page from another pc inside my network i have this error:

> 'pidof' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I have a felling that the php page is executed on the pc where i open the page.
I have tried many solution but none seems to work.

What is the best solution to run a command inside my server with php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the command `which pidof`. Change the command inside the exec to include this full path:

`which pidof
/bin/pidof`

The resulting code will be:

```
exec("/bin/pidof /var/www/cpp/main 2>&1", $output,$return);

if ($return == 0) {
    $isProcessRunning=true;
} else {
    $isProcessRunning=false;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your fast reply, After i have run "which pidof" i have the same result like you, so i used the same command like you "/bin/pidof /var/www/cpp/main 2>&1". But now i have this error : "The system cannot find the path specified.". I still think the problem is that the php try to run the command on the PC where i open the page, and not in the server.